# Getting list of artifact dependencies of a project from a Mojo

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a Maven 3 plugin.

I need the list of dependencies (as `org.apache.maven.artifact.Artifact`s) defined in the POM of the project that my plugin is run over.

To that end I have this field in a Mojo of mine:

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${what.do.I.need.here}")
private MavenProject project;
```

I want to use it like this:

```
`this.project.getArtifacts();`
```

and get the list of dependencies.

So I'm kind of confused by the, what to me looks like, a lot of fragmented documentation on the question.

So can someone point me to a relevant documentation on this or point me in the right direction ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation should be `@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")`.

As for the artifacts, you need to understand which of the three classpaths you want: Compile, test or runtime? The elements on each of those depends on the [dependency scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Use `project.getCompileArtifacts()`, `project.getTestArtifacts()` and `project.getRuntimeArtifacts()` respectively to get the lists of dependencies.

Comment: Just a quick question. Which docs did you use for the info ? If you know it by memory do you remember where you first read it ? I find the apache docs on the topic quite fragmented and unclear.

Comment: For things like this, I never look into the docs - they can be outdated, wrong or confusing. In this case, I look at the source code of a mojo: https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ning/maven/plugins/duplicatefinder/DuplicateFinderMojo.java